# no error on console, making little circles change colour on refresh

Tags: javascript, codepen

I have been trying to complete a small exercise and I have it running in codepen but when I put it through sublime and open it in my browser it doesn't show anything! I have tried running it through JSHint, read over and over it. Would love if someone one could please take a moment to have a quick read through.
..This is what it's supposed to do.. http://codepen.io/hellojessicagraham/pen/Ropgob

```
var htmlDot = "";
var red;
var green;
var blue;
var rgbColor;


function colourSelect() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 );
}

for(var i = 1; i<=100; i+=1) {
    red = colourSelect();
    green = colourSelect();
    blue = colourSelect();
    rgbColor = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
    htmlDot += "<div style=\"background-color:"+ rgbColor + " \"></div>";
}
document.write(htmlDot);
```

The HTML is as follows

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"> 
</head>
<body>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS as follows

```
div{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
```

}

Thank you in advance

Comment: The code looks fine; however, the divs will collapse into nothing if they don't have content inside of them or have been given a specific height and width. Where is your css?

Comment: Please check the inspector and see what is written in the console. Add the error to your post and please change the title to reflect something more specific (such as the error you're getting in your console), otherwise this post may be closed do to how broad your title is.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems to work with all the code on your html document, are you sure the links to your js/css files are correct ? Use the inspector in your navigator (F12) if you're not sure.

Edit : It's just working fine. Like Dejan said, your error is probably in your stylesheet.

```js
var htmlDot = "";
var red;
var green;
var blue;
var rgbColor;


function colourSelect() {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 );
}

for(var i = 1; i<=100; i+=1) {
 red = colourSelect();
 green = colourSelect();
 blue = colourSelect();
 rgbColor = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
 htmlDot += "<div style=\"background-color:"+ rgbColor + " \"></div>";
}
document.write(htmlDot);
```

```css
button {
  width:50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I've checked that and unfortunately it's not that

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code is fine, all u forgot is the css of the div element. Your divs are all collapesed into oneand not displaying. Give them some love :D LIke in the link u posted they created circles with the folowing css.

```
.div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, my css is linked to my html I just didn't think want to make my question too long and off putting so I didn't put it in my question, but I've added it in there now. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no

```
<body>
```

Also, try to remove

```
  <!doctype html>
```

Actually, it works fine.Try to make sure about the path and the file name.

[image]

Comment: why remove `<!doctype html>`?

Comment: @1252748 Because it counts as an error in http://codepen.io/hellojessicagraham/pen/Ropgob